# make the background of a webbrowser transparent

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make the background of my web browser transparent like wb.setBackground(Color.transparent) in android.

is it even possible ?

thanks,

Renaud

Comment: What's your expected behaviour? would you want the pages within the control to lose their background, or are you looking into making the control translucent?

Comment: if the page i'm loading into it doesn't have a background, will I see the color of the container they're in ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WebBrowser control is not a true Silverlight control and so **does not support the ability** to make the background transparent.

Sorry, it's just not possible with the currently available tools.
It is a highly requested feature though and so this may (hopefully) change in a future version.

Comment: &@$# me ! :) ok thanks very much (you helped me several times !) !

Comment: can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566872/webbrowser-control-with-transparent-background

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to [Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) you can change the brush of the background:

```
SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
wb.Bacground = scb;
```

Or you can make the whole control transparent

```
wb.Opacity = 0.0;
```

But the question is: Is it a good idea?

Comment: hum, what i mean to do, is not make my webbrower disapear, I just want to see the background of my panorama container to have the paralax effect. sorry if I wasn't clear, Or maybe i haven't understant your answer