# Webbrowser control with Transparent background

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

I am working on Windows phone 8 app.

This is my code:

i am binding the data in the XAML:

```
<phone:WebBrowser  IsScriptEnabled="True"
                                       ScriptNotify="BrowserControlScriptNotify"
                                       ListBoxWebView:WebBrowserUtility.Html="{Binding WebView}"/>
```

here `WebView` is the `data binded to webbrowser control`.

I have the content like this:

```
<html><head>{0}</head><body bgcolor=BGCOLOR style=\"margin:0px;padding:0px;\" "
```

here `bgcolor=BGCOLOR` i want the  bgcolor to be transparent.

i have tried `<body style="background: transparent; margin: 0; padding: 0;">` but its not working.

Comment: The `WebBrowser` control isn't actually WPF, so in general it is not going to blend into the rest of your app that well. You can't make it transparent, among other changes you'd normally want to make to a UI element.

Comment: @steveg89 if i dont set `bgcolor` it gives me default white color, but i want it to be transparent

Comment: My point is, because of the actual underlying design of the control, you won't be able to have a transparent background. It always renders above the other controls and always has some color to it. Opacity, and by extension transparency, are not supported on this control.

Comment: @steveg89 ok i got your point , but is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I ran into this when playing around with showing HTML in one of my apps but ended up going a different route because of this same issue. I couldn't blend the WebBrowser into my UI so it just looked like crap. I was under the impression that 8.1 was bringing an updated control that might solve your issue. Otherwise, I don't know of a solution on the mobile side.

Comment: @Goofy Attempting to make a web browser control transparent is like trying to be able to see through internet explorer by setting the HTML to transparent. That isn't how the control works or is rendered on the UI.

Comment: @AMR ok, but but can we do something in `BrowserControlScriptNotify`

Comment: @Goofy BrowserControlScriptNotify allows your program to execute javascript dynamically. The JavaScript isn't going to modify the XAML control that contains the browser. It will only modify the HTML and Javascript within the source itself. '

Comment: @Goofy You are basically asking the jelly inside of a donut to tell the box that it's in to open its lid.

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with the WebBrowser control, but I would think it would accept an Alpha Channel declaration via RGB like `background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0);` that might be worth trying.

Answer (score 4):

As per the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10737268/1755) (and you've seen), it is not possible to make the background of a webbrowser control transparent.

As an alternative, you could use an image of the page without the webbrowser control displayed as the background of the HTML page you're displaying.

A couple of provisos though:
Obviously this wouldn't work with a page that has content that moves or changes.
If the XAML page content isn't fixed then you'll need to create a bitmap of the screen to use as the background.
You may have to be careful with the relative path to the image (from HTML).
This is untested, by me, and just an idea.