# Change colour of substring

Tags: c#, string, winforms

Is this possible? For example, if I had a label:

```
lblsentence.Text = "Blue is my favourite colour, and Red is my least favourite"
```

Could I change `"Blue"` and `"Red"` to different colours, and leave the rest of the label text default (Black)?

Comment: strings are colourless, do you mean you you want to change a labels colour?

Comment: Which API are you using? WindowsForms? WPF? Silverlight? Asp.NET?
(and of course I am totally agree with @Sayse)

Comment: Without more context, this is kind of like asking if you can make 8 green instead of pink.

Comment: I think you mean to change the color of the html control assigned to this string?

Comment: Do you have particular set of colors?

Comment: Which technology? Winforms, asp.net? wpf?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi not really concerned. Whatever C#/WinForms has to offer.

Comment: I don't think a label in winforms can have multiple colours, you may need to make a user control that can contain multiple (dynamic) labels that are positioned in a way that makes it look like a single label

Comment: You could use a Rich Text Boxt, and set its properties so it acts as a label.  RTB supports several colors in text.

Comment: You can owner draw a label to have multiple colors and fonts. Not really hard. See an example on [CoderEview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55916/a-lightweight-rich-link-label)

Comment: @Ben: A modified answer has been posted in which you can use System.Drawing.Color to obtain the list of colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below.

**for Web**

```
Type colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
// We take only static property to avoid properties like Name, IsSystemColor ...
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] propInfos = colorType.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
string[] Colors = propInfos.Select(m => m.Name).ToArray();
string str = lblsentence.Text;
foreach(string color in Colors)
{
    if(str.Contains(color))
    {
        string replaceColor = "<span style='color:" + color + "'>" + color + "</span>";
        str = str.Replace(color, replaceColor);
    }
}
lblsentence.Text = str;
```

**For Windows Forms**

We can use WebBrowser control in case of Win-Forms rather than Label control.

```
string str = "Blue is my favourite colour, and Red is my least favourite";
Type colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
// We take only static property to avoid properties like Name, IsSystemColor ...
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] propInfos = colorType.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
string[] Colors = propInfos.Select(m => m.Name).ToArray();

foreach (string color in Colors)
{
    if (str.Contains(color))
    {
        string replaceColor = "<span style='color:" + color + "'>" + color + "</span>";
        str = str.Replace(color, replaceColor);
    }
}            
webBrowser1.DocumentText = str;
```

Comment: @Shell: For WinForms, you can use WebBrowser control rather than Label, answer modified for the same.

Comment: background color depends on the requirements. If my form is white, it will look perfect. And apart from that, it is not mentioned in the asked question.

Comment: check this out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566872/webbrowser-control-with-transparent-background) for more information and better to be constructive rather than destructive.

Comment: @Shell: And We're not here to develop the whole application, we are here to give people an idea like how they can overcome their issues by our solutions. Lets allow them to adopt if it fits in their requirement. Don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with the Rich Text Box control

```
        // set the selection at the end of the box and set selection to 0
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;


        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
        richTextBox1.AppendText("hello ");

        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        richTextBox1.AppendText("World");

        // set back the default color
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = richTextBox1.ForeColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, Wiforms label doesn't support multiple fore colors. You either need a `RichTextBox` or a custom control.

I suggest you to use [HtmlRenderer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32376/A-Professional-HTML-Renderer-You-Will-Use) library, which provides `HtmlLabel` control which you can use. All you have to do is convert the text to a valid `Html`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u draw your own text on your form. `e.Graphics.DrawString()` will help you.

```
private void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Font font = this.Font;

    int iLocation = 10;

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Blue", font, Brushes.Blue, new PointF(iLocation, 100));
    iLocation += e.Graphics.MeasureString("Blue", font) + 5;    

    e.Graphics.DrawString(" is my favourite colour, and ", font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(iLocation, 100));
    iLocation += e.Graphics.MeasureString(" is my favourite colour, and ", font) + 5;

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Red", font, Brushes.Red, new PointF(iLocation, 100));
    iLocation += e.Graphics.MeasureString("Red", font) + 5;

    e.Graphics.DrawString(" is my least favourite", font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(iLocation, 100));    
}
```

Comment: This is not generic, What if i have Yellow or Green in the string?

Comment: OP did not mentioned that. BTW, we can get the color from the color name using `Color.FromName(string colorname)` method.

Comment: We should answer in generic way and OP just have given an example of colored string. Can you make it generic?